# How do I implement my own "swipe" gesture recognizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I'm wondering if I'm not overcomplicating this. First off, the reason I want my own "swipe" is to get both the start and end touches of the swipe, and the ability to create a compound gesture (multiple swipes would be recognized as a single gesture -- example: glyph-like pattern recognition).

Anyways, I'm tracking metrics during touchesMoved: but I do not have a good way to make sure that the user's touch is on a line or even if the velocity is valid. I'm finding that the touchesMoved: callback provides touch samples that deviate a fair bit (touchesMoved: samples have included deviation of more than 50%). My thoughts for doing this in touchesMoved: is two fold. One, to ensure that the swipe is straight, and two, to cancel the gesture if necessary.

Here's my touchesMoved:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *currentTouch = (UITouch *)[touches anyObject];
    CGPoint curTouchPoint = [self.view.window
                             convertPoint:[currentTouch locationInView:self.view.window]
                             toWindow:nil];
    CGPoint prevTouchPoint = [self.view.window
                              convertPoint:[currentTouch previousLocationInView:self.view.window]
                              toWindow:nil];

    // Swipe and touch metrics    
    CGFloat touchLength = [SwipeGestureRecognizer lineDistanceForStartPoint:prevTouchPoint endPoint:curTouchPoint];
    CGFloat touchVelocity = touchLength / (currentTouch.timestamp - _prevTouchTime);
    CGFloat touchAngle = [SwipeGestureRecognizer angleForStartPoint:prevTouchPoint endPoint:curTouchPoint];

    CGFloat prevTouchVelocity = _prevTouchVelocity;
    _prevTouchVelocity *= _sampleWeight;
    _prevTouchVelocity += (1.0f - _sampleWeight) * touchVelocity;

    CGFloat prevTouchAngle = _prevTouchAngle;
    _prevTouchAngle *= _sampleWeight;
    _prevTouchAngle += (1.0f - _sampleWeight) * touchAngle;

    _prevTouchTime = currentTouch.timestamp;
}
```

At this point I'm unsure how to "validate" the swipe. I understand that things like velocity could be subjective but I was hoping that some of you pros have done this before and have some input.

Comment: I always use `[[event allTouches] anyObject]` instead of the `touches` set.

Comment: If you do your calculations in touchesMoved, then you need to save a point earlier than always just using the last point to compare to the current point, due to how dramatically different a given sequence of points will be during a swipe. What methods you use to validate the earlier points along the swipe would be the special sauce. I bet there are a number of examples of other users with similar needs.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any examples honestly. I've found some issues at the beginning of the touch (where the samples are very misleading), so I'm going to introduce a sample confidence metric.